# Dynamically change observation array length in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, agent

I try to do a reinforcement learning enviroment with tf_agents in Tensorflow.
Is it possible to dynamically change the size of the observation array?

For example I want the agent to learn to find the minimum path in a weighted graph, so each episode I create a random graph. Each step the agent is on a vertex and the observation array contains the outgoing edge weights. Sometimes there is 1 but sometimes more, so the size is not constant.
I define the observation like this in the enviroment's **init** function, where n is the number of outgoing edges from the start vertex:

```
self._observation_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(shape=(1,n), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, name='observation')
```

If later on I want to change the size of the array it raises an error (*ValueError given time_spec does not match expected*...).

Is it possible to get around this error or do I need to change the structure of the enviroment in this example?

Answer (score 0):

It is definetly not possible to change the size of your observation (even if your could pass this ArraySpec check, your agent cannot manage differently sized inputs). I suggest reformatting your environment so that it supports graphs where each node has a maximum of `x` neighbours and you just output a multi-hot encoded vector of size `x`.